# Connecting of quickblox server

Tags: xamarin

I also having a problem when connecting to QuickBlox server. The error given is "Token is required" and it also reproduces in the official Xamarin Sample, which in the past was working fine.

Comment: please find the solution and give to me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should provide more information, please take the [tour] and read [ask].